# Adding One More Link In Highslide Caption Area

Tags: highslide

I am using this highslide example for my site:-
.

http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-in-page-with-large-imagelink-in-caption.html
.

I need to add another link beside the existing link in the caption area. How do I do it?
.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That example shows how to put a dynamic, automatically-generated link in the caption area. But you can take a much more direct approach. In short, you can put whatever HTML you want in a caption. For example, the thumbnail might look like this, producing two text links in the caption:

```
<a href='slides/bears1.jpg' class='highslide' onclick='return hs.expand(this)'>
<img src='thumbs/bears1.jpg' width='124' height='93' alt='bears1' title=''></a>
<div class='highslide-caption'>This is the basic caption.<br>This is <a href='http://cnn.com'>a link to CNN</a>.<br>This is <a href='http://nbcnews.com'>a link to NBC News</a>.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, EarlyOut, for the help.

I tried your suggested solution, but it works only if I remove the "InPageOption" setting. But I need that setting to be left intact, as I need the gallery to function as it is designed. When I removed the "InPageOptions" setting, all the three links show up, but then the programs does not function like it did before.

If I just add the code as you suggested, the additional links do not show up in the captions area at all.

Is there a way to overcome the problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this new demo: http://roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-in-page-with-large-imagelink-in-caption-and-additional-link.html This is a modification of the [demo](http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-in-page-with-large-imagelink-in-caption.html) you already are using.

Replace this in the old demo:

```
// Inserting link to large image in caption
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterGetCaption = function(sender) {
    if (sender.caption) {
        sender.caption.innerHTML += '<br /><a href="' + sender.content.src + '" class="highslide" onclick="return stopSlideshowAndExpand(this, largeImage)">View large image</a>';
    }
};
```

With this:

```
// Inserting link to large image and additional link in the caption
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterGetCaption = function(sender) {
    if (sender.caption) {
        sender.caption.innerHTML += '<br /><a href="' + sender.content.src + '" class="highslide" onclick="return stopSlideshowAndExpand(this, largeImage)">View large image</a><br /><a href="' + this.custom.url + '" class="highslide" target="_blank"><span style="font-size: 12px; font-style: italic;">Go to ' + this.custom.linktext + ' </span><span style="font-size: 7px; font-style: italic;">(opens in new tab)</span></a>';
    }
};
```

The HTML markup of the image in the new demo looks like this:

```
<a class='highslide' href='images/016.large.jpg' onclick="return hs.expand(this, inPageOptions, {url: 'http://highslide.com/ref/', linktext: 'Highslide API reference page'} )">
    <img src='images/016.smallthumb.jpg' alt='Autumn leaves'/>
</a>
```

Replace the content of `url` and `linktext` with your own url and text.

Comment: Thank you, Roadrash, for your kind and good help. Much appreciated.

My page is specially for tablets. Is it possible to position the link to be on the left side (*aligned left, and preferably on the same line*)? Is it possible to use a small image for the link?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Hilde, please disregard my last question, as I have modified the suggested solution, which worked marvellously. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sorry to bring this matter up again now. As the text link is too small for me, how can I replace it with, or add a graphic link? What is the syntax? Many thanks.

Comment: (comment 1 of 2) I assume you want to use the same graphic for the links in the captions. Replace this line in the onAfterExpand event: `sender.caption.innerHTML += '<br /><a href="' + sender.content.src + '" class="highslide" onclick="return stopSlideshowAndExpand(this, largeImage)">View large image</a><br /><a href="' + this.custom.url + '" class="highslide" target="_blank"><span style="font-size: 12px; font-style: italic;">Go to ' + this.custom.linktext + ' </span><span style="font-size: 7px; font-style: italic;">(opens in new tab)</span></a>';` (continues in next comment -->)

Comment: (comment 2 of 2 <-- from my previous comment)
with this: `sender.caption.innerHTML += '<br /><a href="' + sender.content.src + '" class="highslide" onclick="return stopSlideshowAndExpand(this, largeImage)">View large image</a><br /><a href="' + this.custom.url + '" target="_blank" title="Go to ' + this.custom.linktext + '"><img src="your-graphic.png" alt="" style="border: none" /></a>';`

Comment: Hi Hilde, I am still with the same example: http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-in-page-with-large-imagelink-in-caption.html . How do I add a caption to the clicked enlarged pop-up image as well? Many thanks.

Comment: See this demo page: http://roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-in-page-with-large-imagelink-in-caption-2.html The changes are in the `onAfterGetCaption` event.

Comment: Thank you. Hilde. Regarding the the thumbnail horizontal strip on that gallery, I want to make the pointer graphic big (say 30px).

Comment: What I meant in the last question is to make the right/left arrow graphic which appears inside the first/last thumbnails big, not the arrow below the thumbnail strip.

Comment: You need to make your own graphic and change the css for the right/left arrow to make it bigger.

Comment: Thank you, Hilde. That is a good solution for my need. I have one more question regarding the same script. When a thumbnail is clicked and if the image file is not found, then the whole script crashes and stopped functioning. I do not encounter this problem. This does not happen with other highslide scripts, as another image will load when I clicked on another thumbnail. How can I solve this?